# jQuery: remove class once element is clicked

Tags: php, jquery

I am stuck on a little jQuery problem. I have a collection of links (more than 50) generated from a php loop. When a user clicks on a link, the jQuery load event is called, and a php/mysql script (called page.php in the example below) is loaded into an empty div on the page.

I would like the class (".classy") to removed from the < a > tag and replaced with another class (".newclass"). This is so that the information is loaded only on the first click.

The html:

```
<a class='classy' name='marvin'>Click to toggle info</a>
<div id='marvin'></div>
```

The jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".classy").click(function(){
        var foo = $(this).attr("name");
        $("#"+foo).load("page.php?id="+foo).slideToggle('fast'); 
        $(this).removeClass('classy');
        $(this).addClass('newclass');
        return false;
    });
});
```

Thanks!

Comment: that code looks fine to me?! (except you should do $(this).removeClass('classy').addClass('newclass') for conciseness) Have you tried seeing what's going on with firebug?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not positive -- but you may need to do it like this (use $.live()) instead:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".classy").live('click', function(){
        var foo = $(this).attr("name");
        $("#"+foo).load("page.php?id="+foo).slideToggle('fast'); 
        $(this).removeClass('classy').addClass('newclass');
        return false;
    });
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Just because you change the class doesn't mean the `click` event handler is removed from the link.  You will need to unbind it manually or just add an `if` statement that checks what class the link has.

Or use `live` function to bind the `click` event.